# CSS overrided rules

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a little CSS problem.

In my html I have something like this:

```
<div class='box-div'>
  <div>Entry 1</div>
  <div class='hide'>Entry 2</div>
</div>
```

In my CSS:

```
.box-div div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

I want the second nested div to be hidden, but the first rule overrides the second one. How can this be solved?

Comment: If absolutely necessary (and for a `hide` class that seems pretty necessary) you can always add `!important` to your style rule: `display: none !important;`. Watch out with them, as they complicate matters a lot if you rely on it.

Comment: Don't use `!important` !

Comment: @Christoph Why is everyone stubbornly saying that? Don't use `!important` unless the situation is right for it. By increasing specificity you lose the power of a class that is simply meant to hide _everything_ that has it as a class, no matter what else. I know that you should _avoid_ `!important` if you can but here it makes perfect sense. It is another tool in our toolbox that does have _at least **some**_ use.

Comment: It can lead to complications though later on in the code. Much better to have your css formatted and written at the same level (this is much better practice).

Comment: @lharby Everyone argues that, but for some specific things it is incredibly useful, like a `hide` class. I have extensively discussed this lower on the page, but basically the argument is that you _want to be 100% sure that a `hide` class is always hidden_. In that case, and `!important` is really useful as you don't have to define it for every specificity.

Comment: @somethinghere Because i think it's not a good idea, tell css newcomers that they should use `!important` for this kind of problems.

Comment: @Christoph _If you explain why and what you can do this_. When your answer is properly motivated and explained, you can help newcomers a lot more than just hand-feeding them a solution without explaining it.

Comment: Inline styles could also solve the issue, but I hope everyone agrees that is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase the strength of yours to make it stronger than the previous rule:

```
.box-div .hide {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
div.hide{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I guess this does defeat the purpose of having a general purpose `hide` class.

Comment: OP could have it named different, but in this case/question thats the only correct answer, increasing specifity

Comment: I don't like !important. !important is the root of all overtime.

Comment: @Mark for Fs sake, you seem intent on being right on an ideological basis right? _This is exactly why !important exists_. It is not to create headaches, but for a **general purpose** class like `.hide` it is usefull as I might want to use it on headers, images, divs, super deeply nested things, etc... The reason it is _right_ here is that increasing specificity is _stupid_ as if you want to hide anything on your site you will have to keep adding every element and give it a .hide class, and that's just working overtime to solve a problem that already has a solution.

Comment: Thank you guys I got it.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do the same.

**1**

```
.box-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**2**

```
.box-div div{
  display: inline-block;
}

div.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**3**

```
.box-div div{
  display: inline-block;
}

div.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**4**

```
.box-div div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.hide.hide  {
  display: none;
}
```

You can strengthen your specificity by repeating it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy

HTML:

```
<div class='box-div'>
  <div>Entry 1</div>
   <div class='hide'>Entry 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-div div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-div > div.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, using a single class of `.hidden` would be a good solution to hide an element on the page regardless of how it is nested. I would want this class to work anywhere.

So I think it might be better to create a class for `dispaly:inline-block` which can be reused.

You could specify that the first div inside `.box-div` always has `inline-block` as a property, but this is very restrictive.

My solution:

```
.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

<div class='box-div'>
  <div class="ib">Entry 1</div>
  <div class='hide'>Entry 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree but it does not solve the specificty issue. For example, if I have a `div#myId { display: block; }` but with your `.hide` class, the `hide` class would be surpressed by the higher specificity `id` definition. Thats actually literally the OPs problem.

Comment: But you do not need to declare display block for a block element. @somethinghere

Comment: @Iharby that's true, but it was an _example_, you could also decide you want an `inline-block`, and _that_ you _do_ need to declare. Then your rule breaks, which is exactly the issue the OP is having - his `.hide` class' `display` property is overwritten by a more specific definition.

Comment: In fairness I am trying to think about the way to do this with the least code and as semantically as possible.

Comment: If that's the case then... (dare I say it? Hmmm... Sure. It _is_ valid...)... you could use `!important` to solve it for this single instance class...

Comment: I feel sorry for the OP now all these contrasting views :/

Comment: Let me round it up by saying: if it is a utility class (as in, when you add a `hide` class it is only for hiding _any_ element and nothing else), then `!important` is fine to use - that's what it's for. If it's styling and specific, then don't use `!important`. But yes, this one is a mess :)